# Documents upload in Xamarin Forms Application

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms

I need to upload the documents (word, pdf or any text file) from the device to server. I could not able to find any samples regarding that. Please help me out or provide some reference solution to solve this...

Comment: any file (document, pdf, image, etc) is just a stream of bytes.  There are numerous examples of how to do this with XF, particularly image upload

Comment: I dont need to upload image. I just need to upload the pdf, words alone. Please share your examples. Thank you..

Comment: Uploading any file type is the SAME, that’s the point.  If you can upload an image you can upload any file.  But it will also depend on your server and how it expects to receive the file

Comment: @ParthibanS You're looking for code here, i'm afraid no one is here to write code for you. Jason's answer pretty much answers your question. Uploading a file can be done in a many different ways, ex- sending byte arrays in  a post request to your server or streams or whatever depends on the API server endpoint.  FYI -> https://github.com/HoussemDellai/UploadFileToServer check this link to get a better understanding.